# Implement an audio loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a node list of audio files and I would like to initiate a audio loop once a play button is pressed. The audio files should play one after another unless manually interrupted.
These are the audio file in the html

```
<div class="audio-tracks">
    <audio data-key="65" src="My_Tracks/Beat for Greg.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Beat For Greg" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/Beat for Greg.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="83" src="My_Tracks/The Sound Of Africa.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="The Sound Of Africa" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/The Sound Of Africa.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="68" src="My_Tracks/Hip hop reagea.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Hip Hop Regea" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/Hip hop reagea.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="70" src="My_Tracks/dancehall 2.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Dancehall Track" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/dancehall 2.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="71" src="My_Tracks/dancehall5.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Another Dancehall Track" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/dancehall5.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="72" src="My_Tracks/Angels sing.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="Angels sing" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/Angels sing.wav"></audio>

    <audio data-key="74" src="My_Tracks/Dreams of peace 2.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="Dreams Of Peace" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/Dreams of peace 2.wav"></audio>

    <audio data-key="75" src="My_Tracks/Yours faithfully.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="Yours Faithfully" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/Yours faithfully.wav"></audio>

    <audio data-key="76" src="My_Tracks/Hard.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Hard" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/Hard.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="90" src="My_Tracks/Gotta be good.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="Gotta Be Good" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/Gotta be good.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="76" src="My_Tracks/In my dreams.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="In My Dreams" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/In my dreams.mp3"></audio>

    <audio data-key="90" src="My_Tracks/A Bigger Crowd.wav"></audio>
    <audio id="A Bigger Crowd" class="tracks" src="My_Tracks/A Bigger Crowd.wav"></audio>
  </div>
```

This is the js file I wrote to try to implement that

```
function globalPlaySound (){
    const audio = document.querySelectorAll('.tracks');
    for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
        audio[i].play();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it plays ALL the audio files at once. What I want is for each file to played individually beginning with the first child element of the audio-tracks div.

Comment: `audioElement.loop = true;` is on... `audioElement.loop = false;` is off, if you want to set dynamically, otherwise just use `<audio loop='true' />`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting audio file information and get its duration then in between the loop you can add delay base on the audio duration. You can check how to get the audio duration using HTML File API. https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/09/23/getting-audio-file-information-with-htmls-file-api-and-audio-element/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code that I found online and that works for me.

```
const playList = document.querySelectorAll('.tracks');

    let playlist = Array.from(playList);
    
    function playNextSounds (playlist){
        if(playlist.length > 0){
            const audio = new Audio();
            audio.src = playlist[0].src;
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            audio.play();
            playlist.shift();
            audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
            playNextSounds(playlist);
            })
        }
    }

    playNextSounds(playlist);
```